# Keycloak Invalid redirect_uri: keycloak automatically resolves my domain name to a CNAME record

Tags: redirect, keycloak, amazon-elb, redirect-uri

I had a service running on AWS with a load balancer (dns name is ***my-loadbalancer-1234567890.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com***).
I also created a CNAME record with name **api.mydomain.com** and value ***my-loadbalancer-1234567890.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com***.
But when setting *Valid redirect URIs* to https://api.mydomain.com/*, it doesn't work. Keycloak automactically resolves and changes redirect uri to ***my-loadbalancer-1234567890.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com***, and show error:

[image]

Do I miss anything? Please help me!

Comment: the redirect_uri is specified by the application using keycloak for login. what is the exact url you get redirected in the browser when trying to login in your application?

Comment: have you find any solution of this problem ?